# Create Azure DevOps task with description

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'd like to open a Bug using the Azure DevOps REST API and create it with a description. I couldn't find in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#workitem) how to do it, I've only seen something about the title.
I've been trying to create a bug with a description by sending this body on the request:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  },
  {
       "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Description",
        "from": null,
        "value": "Test of REST functionality"
  }
]
```

But still no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work item type `Bug` does not have the field `Description`. Instead, it has the field called `Steps to Reproduce`, which is probably what you're trying to set.

So, first of all you need to specify the `type` URI parameter to be a `Bug`, and change the payload to something like the following:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Test of REST functionality"
  }
]
```

I can't verify this to be 100% sure at the moment but hope this gives you enough information to try it out.

Comment: Thank you!! I also thought that, because there's no "description" input when creating a bug through the interface , but there's repro steps... I can't find a documentation that explain these fields paths and what's their meaning, do you have some material that could help me with that?

Comment: This article gives a pretty good idea: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/get-work-item-type-fields?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1